# Is it possible to create such graphic elements in Adobe Illustrator? (please see images)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

I came up with a series of logos where i saw nicely drawn ornaments which are nicely beveled and look like 3D. I tried to make them in illustrator but i couldn't do it as good because of the limitations on using gradients on brush strokes. The special thing about them is that the gradient is applied along the strokes of those floras and they look beveled and realistic. Is it possible to do such designs in Adobe Illustrator? If yes, what would your technique be to do that? Thanks! (sorry about the quality of the images it was a screenshot).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd use Photoshop for such a graphic - since it's generally better for smooth bevel and drop shadow effects which can be applied as layer effects. See example here: https://imgur.com/a/5Ivq1tz

Comment: @billyKerr thank you, seems a great idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Set the stroke width and change the **Profile** type (1)
- Add a gradient to the stroke and choose **Apply Gradient Across
  Stroke** (2)

[image]